# Google OAuth - disallowed_useragent on Mobiles using SignIn Card

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-api, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, google-authentication

I am trying to implement google authentication in xamarin forms application and I have tried different links such as:
1. Xamarin.Auth sdk.
2. https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Google-Login-Xamarin-Forms 
But, each time I get 403 disallowed_useragent error as google has deprecated webviews in xamarin forms. Can you please help me find some new approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Below links are definitely worth looking because they provided accepted solutions.

***Github:***

[Change the user-agent to directly launch a browser in the Mobile as opposed to the default WebView](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3659)

***Youtube:***
[User agent modification Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFSgIdtEl2k)